# Android: How to add button to "Control Center"

Tags: android, user-interface, button, controls

I recently downloaded an app and it added a toggle button on the "Control Center" (I don't know how this section is called).

I am trying to develop an app and this feature would really help me, but I can't seem to find anything on how to implement it.

What is this area called and how do I create a button which can be added to it?

[image: screenshot of MIUI Control Center]

[image: screenshot of MIUI Control Center]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is called QuickSettings tiles - [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService).

Here are some links with examples on how to implement those:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8
https://gist.github.com/jerrellmardis/e990b2ff6a5e349e5041ad4d13639af1

Note, that this API is only available from Android 7.0 (API 24).